# how to merge two projects (SFC) into one in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-sfc

I have downloaded a beautiful menu (SFC VueJS) and I would like to implement that to another SFC that I have. I've tried everything but always complain about missing things in the folder node_modules.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

---

The packages I'm trying to merge are:

vue-google-charts
vue-sidebar-menu

What I'm trying todo is to have the menu and the charts together. When I run the SFC individually it works fine, but if I try to merge then importing everything that needs to be imported in the App.vue, it complains about the node_modules that is in the folder of the other project (For example, I have added the code in Google Charts in the App.vue of the sidebar).

I'm a newbie in Vuejs. Watched a few videos, played around a bit and managed to do what I want, but adding a menu in the project I would like to use the sidebar.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that menu also available as `module` on npmjs.com? Then you could use it that way. Otherwise, could you please give us the code where the error is thrown and a more detailed error message?

Comment: We do need more details but the problem seems to me that whatever code you downloaded is using some npm package that you are missing, you need to look at the imports of the components youve downloaded and install their related packages using npm, to find the version of the packages you could look into `package.json` file from the original code source.